# JUNG: adding children to DelegateTree after having drawn it

Tags: java, swing, tree, visualization, jung

I'm developing a Java application and I'm using the JUNG library.
In my application I first create a `DelegateTree` and draw it to the screen:

```
public static GraphZoomScrollPane generateTree(Tree tree,
    GraphicalUserInterface gui) {

    /* Create a new tree */
    edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Tree<Node, Edge> graphTree = new DelegateTree<Node, Edge>();

    /* Add all nodes and vertices to the tree */
    graphTree.addVertex(tree.getRoot());
    addChildren(tree.getRoot(), graphTree);

    /* Create the visualization */
    TreeLayout<Node, Edge> treeLayout = new TreeLayout<Node, Edge>(graphTree);
    VisualizationViewer<Node, Edge> vv = new VisualizationViewer<Node, Edge>(treeLayout);
    vv.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller<Edge>());
    vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeShapeTransformer(new EdgeShape.Line<Node, Edge>());
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller<Node>());
    vv.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Renderer.VertexLabel.Position.S);

    vv.addGraphMouseListener(new ClickNode(gui, vv));
    final DefaultModalGraphMouse<Node, Edge> graphMouse = new DefaultModalGraphMouse<Node, Edge>();
    graphMouse.setMode(ModalGraphMouse.Mode.TRANSFORMING);
    vv.setGraphMouse(graphMouse);

    return new GraphZoomScrollPane(vv);
}
```

Afterwards the user is able to add new children to the leaves of my tree. But when I just do

```
graphTree.addEdge(edge, parent, child);
```

and then redraw the `VisualizationViewer`, the visualization lost the 'Tree' structure. It just adds the child somewhere above the parent and all other children of that new child right on top of it.

Is there a better way to dynamically add children to the leaves of my tree? Or do I have to use something else for redrawing instead of just `vv.repaint()`?

Any help would really be appreciated.

An example of what happens:

http://www.dylankiss.be/JUNGExample.PNG

Starting with just the root (OUTLOOK), after adding 3 children (Leaf, Leaf, Leaf) with different edges (sunny, overcast, rainy), they just appear on top of each other.

**EDIT**: This is the `addChildren()` method.

```
private static void addChildren(Node node, edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Tree<Node, Edge> tree) {
    for (int i = 0; i < node.getChildren().size(); i++) {
        tree.addEdge(new Edge(node.getChildren().get(i).getParentValue()), node, node.getChildren().get(i));
        addChildren(node.getChildren().get(i), tree);
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**: This is the part of an AWT ActionListener where I add new children to the tree.

```
while (there are still edges to be added) {
    value = name of new edge;
    child = new Node(this.m_node, value);
    this.m_node.addChild(child);
    graphTree.addEdge(new Edge(value), this.m_node, child);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting the method that is in charge of adding new edges would help here :)

But at first glance, it seems that you are adding 3 different edges between the same two nodes (OUTLOOK and Leaf). I'm guessing you are doing this (or the equivalent with Node and Edge instances):

```
graphTree.addChild("sunny", "OUTLOOK", "Leaf");
graphTree.addChild("overcast", "OUTLOOK", "Leaf");
graphTree.addChild("rainy", "OUTLOOK", "Leaf");
```

In this case, as JUNG graphs maintain unicity of nodes, you end up with only two nodes, and 3 different edges between them. When JUNG tries to display this graph, you will get the two nodes and the 3 overlapping edges as you used EdgeShape.Line.

If you original goal was indeed to set 3 different edges between two nodes, try using different edge shapes to avoid overlapping and get a better rendering, e.g. EdgeShape.BentLine or such.

If you wanted 3 different nodes, you will have to use 3 different names, or 3 different Node instances *which are not equals*.

Good luck :)

**EDIT**:

Following your comment, I took a look at the TreeLayout sources, and there is a small issue which makes it impossible to dynamically update the layout.

**To fix the problem**, use this class instead:

```
import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.TreeLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.Collection;

import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Forest;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util.TreeUtils;

public class DynamicTreeLayout<V, E>
    extends TreeLayout<V, E>
{
public DynamicTreeLayout(Forest<V, E> g) {
    this(g, DEFAULT_DISTX, DEFAULT_DISTY);
}

public DynamicTreeLayout(Forest<V, E> g, int distx) {
    this(g, distx, DEFAULT_DISTY);
}

public DynamicTreeLayout(Forest<V, E> g, int distx, int disty) {
    super(g, distx, disty);
}

protected void buildTree() {
    alreadyDone.clear(); // This was missing and prevented the layout to update positions

    this.m_currentPoint = new Point(20, 20);
    Collection<V> roots = TreeUtils.getRoots(graph);
    if (roots.size() > 0 && graph != null) {
        calculateDimensionX(roots);
        for (V v : roots) {
            calculateDimensionX(v);
            m_currentPoint.x += this.basePositions.get(v) / 2 + this.distX;
            buildTree(v, this.m_currentPoint.x);
        }
    }
}

private int calculateDimensionX(V v) {
    int localSize = 0;
    int childrenNum = graph.getSuccessors(v).size();

    if (childrenNum != 0) {
        for (V element : graph.getSuccessors(v)) {
            localSize += calculateDimensionX(element) + distX;
        }
    }
    localSize = Math.max(0, localSize - distX);
    basePositions.put(v, localSize);

    return localSize;
}

private int calculateDimensionX(Collection<V> roots) {
    int localSize = 0;
    for (V v : roots) {
        int childrenNum = graph.getSuccessors(v).size();

        if (childrenNum != 0) {
            for (V element : graph.getSuccessors(v)) {
                localSize += calculateDimensionX(element) + distX;
            }
        }
        localSize = Math.max(0, localSize - distX);
        basePositions.put(v, localSize);
    }

    return localSize;
}
}
```

You will also need to add the following if you want the layout to be updated and the viewer to be repainted for each modification of your graph:

```
layout.setGraph(g);
vv.repaint();
```

Comment: What the `addChildren()` method does, is look whether my Node object has children, and if so, create distinct edges (`new Edge(...)`) for each child, pointing from the parent node to the child, and then recursively call the `addChildren()` method on every child.

Every Node and Edge I add are all new and so distinct objects. When I use an existing tree and I call the `generateTree()` method, it nicely draws my tree as I want. It just doesn't work when I add nodes after I've drawn it for the first time.

Comment: I had a look at the TreeLayout class, and there is a small bug which prevent it from updating the node positions when new nodes are created. See my updated initial answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! Adding this new class worked like a charm.

Comment: An additional question: when I add new children to a parent node, they seem to be added randomly and not in the order I added them. Would that have something to do with the new DynamicTreeLayout?